# When to provide explicit binding and when to leverage the automatic binding on Guice

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I was wonder, why do we need to provide bindings explicitly sometimes and not other times in the module?
How does Guice decide when we need the binding and when not?

Is it because if a dependency has no multiple implementations and it is injected elsewhere as a dependencies it will be automatically bound as part of a dependency graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a binding (either through a `bind`, an `@Provides` method or an `@ImplementedBy` annotation) for anything you want injected that is not a concrete class with a no-arg constructor or an `@Inject` annotated constructor.