# Guice Injection: parameter not explicity bound

Tags: java, guice, code-injection

I am trying to convert some code into a new format and am running into an issue with the dropwizard resources. This is the resource class which I have added inject to

```
@Inject
public TestResource(TestDAO testDAO, String path) {
```

TestDAO being a class which extends io.dropwizard.hibernate.AbstractDAO. When I try to run this with injection I receive

```
1) Explicit bindings are required and ...TestDAO is not explicitly bound.
  while locating ...TestDAO
    for the 1st parameter of TestResource.<init>(TestResource.java:44)

2) Explicit bindings are required and java.lang.String is not explicitly bound.
  while locating java.lang.String
    for the 2nd parameter of ...TestResource.<init>(TestResource.java:44)
```

Comment: Where do you think you have explicitly bound those parameter

Comment: I never said I thought I was. I don't know what I need to do for explicit bindings. I'm new to Java. I looked at other projects that use this and the documentation and I don't see what I am supposed to add.

Answer (score 2):

There was a class that was generated in this template that extended AbstractModule. In that there was an override on configure() which had the bindings.

```
bind(TestResource.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

I also needed to modify my DAO classes so that they could support injection.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause is well explained here [When to provide explicit binding and when to leverage the automatic binding on Guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364976/when-to-provide-explicit-binding-and-when-to-leverage-the-automatic-binding-on-g)

However for me it was because not all wars got deployed. In Eclipse's Tomcat *Add and Remove...* interface I failed to include all wars that were part of application module that I wanted to launch.